# I am doing an angular migration from 8 to 9 and it happens that I have this error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey I am doing an Angular migration from 8 to 9
And I have been tracking errors and trying to fix them except those one that I had in multiple lines of code

**ERROR in angularApp/app/my-trades/my-trades.component.ts:2045:34 - error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'unknown'.**

This is where I get the error

```
private paginate() {


        this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
            map(params => params.get('page'))) // here it underlines  get
            .subscribe(page => {
                if (page) {
                    this.config.currentPage = Number(page);
                };
            });

    }
```

This is my package.json

````
```
{
    "name": "project.vision",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "scripts": {
        "build:production": "npm run ng:build:production",
        "ng:build": "ng build",
        "ng:build:production": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer",
        "ng:build:production-withstats": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --stats-json",
        "ng:watch": "ng build --watch  --aot --source-map --deleteOutputPath=true",
        "stats": "webpack-bundle-analyzer wwwroot/stats.json"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/upgrade": "^7.1.0",
        "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^2.0.0",
        "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.0-preview.1.21103.6",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.0",
        "ajv": "^6.9.1",
        "angular2-draggable": "^1.4.2",
        "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.6",
        "apexcharts": "^3.25.0",
        "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "breeze-bridge2-angular": "^1.1.0",
        "breeze-client": "^1.6.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
        "core-js": "^3.17.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
        "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
        "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
        "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
        "flatted": "^2.0.1",
        "glslify": "^6.1.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
        "lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
        "microsoft-adal-angular6": "^1.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.8",
        "ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7": "^0.1.5",
        "ng2-charts": "2.2.3",
        "ng5-slider": "^1.1.14",
        "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
        "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.2",
        "plotly.js": "^1.45.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "rxjs": "^7.3.0",
        "saturn-datepicker": "^7.2.0",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^1.12.0",
        "@types/applicationinsights-js": "1.0.7",
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
        "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.35",
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.9.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.2",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
        "@types/lodash-es": "4.14.2",
        "@types/node": "10.12.7",
        "@types/plotly.js": "^1.44.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.9.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
        "karma": "^6.3.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
        "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "^6.1.3",
        "typescript": "3.6.3",
        "webpack": "^5.51.2",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.6.1"
    },
    "browser": {
        "image-size": false
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "typescript": "3.6.4",
        "tslib": "1.10.0"
    }
}
```


My imports are :
````

```
import { auditTime, debounceTime, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewEncapsulation, OnDestroy, Injector, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Predicate, FilterQueryOp, core, EntityQuery } from 'breeze-client';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Deal } from './../shared/models/deal';
import { Client } from './../shared/models/client';
import { CodeValue } from './../shared/models/code-value';
import { MessageService } from './../shared/services/message-service';
import { Product } from './../shared/models/product';
import { ContextService } from './../shared/services/context-service';
import { Functions } from './../shared/services/func-service';
import { UserContextProvider } from './../shared/services/user-context-provider';
import { RootEditComponent } from './../shared/components/root/root-edit.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';
import { Seller } from '../shared/models/seller';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { TradeFilterStorage } from '../shared/models/tradeFilterStorage';
import { EntityCount } from '../shared/models/entity-count';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Invoice } from "../shared/models/invoice";
import { GeneratedInvoice } from "../shared/models/GeneratedInvoice";
declare var adalconfig: any;
import { FileBlob } from "../shared/models/file-blob";
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import { NumberHelper } from '../shared/helpers/number.helper';
import { Quality } from '../shared/models/quality';
import { IssuerBookingEntity } from '../shared/models/issuer-office';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Issuer } from '../shared/models/issuer';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ExportToCsv } from 'export-to-csv';
import { ClientRelation } from '../shared/models/clientRelation';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-trades-component',
    styleUrls: ['./my-trades.component.scss'],
    providers: [ContextService, Functions, UserContextProvider],
    templateUrl: 'my-trades.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Comment: What are your imports in the class? How is `route` defined?

Comment: I just added them in the question field

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typo in the code you posted, but you do have an extra single quote right before the comment, which may cause weird things to happen. Beyond that, [try typing the params variable](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParamMap):

```
    this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
        map(params: ParamMap => params.get('page')))
```

Comment: indeed it was a typo , I've tried what you just posted but no results 
this time it says that : TS2304 :(TS) Cannot find name 'params'. 
I've tried this one and it seems syntaxically right  but no idea if it will work as the previous one ``` map(params => params['get']('page'))) ```